# The getter 'length' isn't defined for the type 'Object'

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I get the following error "The getter 'length' isn't defined for the type 'Object'" when checking the length of snapshot.data in the itemCount property of a listViewBuilder:

```
child: StreamBuilder(
       stream:_firestoreService?.getProducts(), 
             builder: (context, snapshot) {
                   if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                          return CircularProgressIndicator();
                   } else {
                          return ListView.builder(
                                 itemExtent: 80,
                                 itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                                 itemBuilder: (context, index) {
```

The data is coming from firestore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the latest versions of the `cloud_firestore` plugin, you need to indicate the type of your query, before you can get the data from it. I recommend checking out the documentation on [migrating to version 2.0](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/2.0.0_migration), which shows that this typically will look something like changing

```
Query query
```

To

```
Query<Map<String, dynamic>> query
```

The exact code you need to change depends on your implementation, and isn't clear from what you shared, but it'll be some type of type annotation like shown above (and in the docs I linked).

Comment: I have made the adjustments but sadly, it's produced no resolution to the issue.

Comment: You were right after all. Although, the call changes a little bit. Thank you

Answer (score 21):

I think the change you need to make is on this line `builder: (context, snapshot)`

When you use that signature, the type that snapshot is assigned is AsyncSnapshot<Object?> , which does not have the `length` getter defined on it.

However, if you modify the builder line to be `builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot)`, then you'll get the `length` getter on `snapshot.data`. Use it as `snapshot.data!.length`.

To sum it up, i think this is what it should be:

```
child: StreamBuilder(
       stream:_firestoreService?.getProducts(), 
             builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                   if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                          return CircularProgressIndicator();
                   } else {
                          return ListView.builder(
                                 itemExtent: 80,
                                 itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                                 itemBuilder: (context, index) {
```

Comment: Nice solution. Work for me.

Answer (score 9):

using AsyncSnapshot snapshot instead of using just snapshot in the code.

That is using

```
builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {}
```

instead of

```
builder: (context, snapshot) {}
```

It worked 10000% for me.